# Canvas is not rendering anything

Tags: webgl, webgl2

I am learning WebGL and while I was trying to do look at after learning it from [webglfundamental2](https://webgl2fundamentals.org/), I wrote this code but this is not throwing any error but there is nothing displayed on the screen.

This is code I tried to render 'F' using the perspective camera.

There is no error in console:

[image: console]

Any help, I can't debug it. Any help, please !!!

```js
"use strict";

const vertexShader = `#version 300 es

    in vec4 a_position;
    in vec4 a_color;

    out vec4 v_color;

    uniform mat4 u_matrix;

    void main(){
        gl_Position = u_matrix*a_position;
        v_color = a_color;
    }
`;


const fragShader = `#version 300 es

    precision highp float;

        in vec4 v_color;
        out vec4 frag_color;

        void main(){
            frag_color = v_color;
        }
`;


function main() {

    var canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
    var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl2");
    if (!gl) {
        return;
    }
    const program = webglUtils.createProgramFromSources(gl, [vertexShader, fragShader]);

    const apositionLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'a_position');
    const acolorLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'a_color');
    const umatrixLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'u_matrix');

    let vao = gl.createVertexArray();
    gl.bindVertexArray(vao);

    let positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
    setGeometry(gl);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(apositionLoc);

    let size = 3;
    let type = gl.FLOAT;
    let normalize = false;
    let stride = 0;
    let offset = 0;
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(apositionLoc, size, type, normalize, stride, offset);

    let colorBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);
    setColor(gl);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(acolorLoc);

    size = 3;
    type = gl.FLOAT;
    normalize = true;
    stride = 0;
    offset = 0;
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(acolorLoc, size, type, normalize, stride, offset);

    let fov = degreeToRadian(60);
    let cameraAngle = degreeToRadian(0);

    function degreeToRadian(deg) {
        return deg * Math.PI / 180;
    }

    drawScene();


    function drawScene() {

        webglUtils.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);

        gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

        gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);

        gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
        
        gl.useProgram(program);

        let aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
        
        let projection = m4.perspective(fov, aspect, 1, 1000);

        let camera = m4.yRotation(cameraAngle);
        camera = m4.translate(camera, 0, 0, -300);
        let viewMatrix = m4.inverse(camera);

        let viewProjection = m4.multiply(projection, viewMatrix);

        gl.uniformMatrix4fv(umatrixLoc, false, viewProjection);
        
        var primitives = gl.TRIANGLES;
        var count = 16*6;
        var offset = 0;
        gl.drawArrays(primitives, count, offset);

    }

}

function setGeometry(gl){

    let positions = new Float32Array([

          0,   0,  0,
          0, 150,  0,
          30,   0,  0,
          0, 150,  0,
          30, 150,  0,
          30,   0,  0,

          // top rung front
          30,   0,  0,
          30,  30,  0,
          100,   0,  0,
          30,  30,  0,
          100,  30,  0,
          100,   0,  0,

          // middle rung front
          30,  60,  0,
          30,  90,  0,
          67,  60,  0,
          30,  90,  0,
          67,  90,  0,
          67,  60,  0,

          // left column back
            0,   0,  30,
           30,   0,  30,
            0, 150,  30,
            0, 150,  30,
           30,   0,  30,
           30, 150,  30,

          // top rung back
           30,   0,  30,
          100,   0,  30,
           30,  30,  30,
           30,  30,  30,
          100,   0,  30,
          100,  30,  30,

          // middle rung back
           30,  60,  30,
           67,  60,  30,
           30,  90,  30,
           30,  90,  30,
           67,  60,  30,
           67,  90,  30,

          // top
            0,   0,   0,
          100,   0,   0,
          100,   0,  30,
            0,   0,   0,
          100,   0,  30,
            0,   0,  30,

          // top rung right
          100,   0,   0,
          100,  30,   0,
          100,  30,  30,
          100,   0,   0,
          100,  30,  30,
          100,   0,  30,

          // under top rung
          30,   30,   0,
          30,   30,  30,
          100,  30,  30,
          30,   30,   0,
          100,  30,  30,
          100,  30,   0,

          // between top rung and middle
          30,   30,   0,
          30,   60,  30,
          30,   30,  30,
          30,   30,   0,
          30,   60,   0,
          30,   60,  30,

          // top of middle rung
          30,   60,   0,
          67,   60,  30,
          30,   60,  30,
          30,   60,   0,
          67,   60,   0,
          67,   60,  30,

          // right of middle rung
          67,   60,   0,
          67,   90,  30,
          67,   60,  30,
          67,   60,   0,
          67,   90,   0,
          67,   90,  30,

          // bottom of middle rung.
          30,   90,   0,
          30,   90,  30,
          67,   90,  30,
          30,   90,   0,
          67,   90,  30,
          67,   90,   0,

          // right of bottom
          30,   90,   0,
          30,  150,  30,
          30,   90,  30,
          30,   90,   0,
          30,  150,   0,
          30,  150,  30,

          // bottom
          0,   150,   0,
          0,   150,  30,
          30,  150,  30,
          0,   150,   0,
          30,  150,  30,
          30,  150,   0,

          // left side
          0,   0,   0,
          0,   0,  30,
          0, 150,  30,
          0,   0,   0,
          0, 150,  30,
          0, 150,   0,

    ]);

    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positions, gl.STATIC_DRAW)
}

function setColor(gl){
gl.bufferData(
      gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
      new Uint8Array([
          // left column front
        200,  70, 120,
        200,  70, 120,
        200,  70, 120,
        200,  70, 120,
        200,  70, 120,
        200,  70, 120,

          // top rung front
        200,  70, 120,
        200,  70, 120,
        200,  70, 120,
        200,  70, 120,
        200,  70, 120,
        200,  70, 120,

          // middle rung front
        200,  70, 120,
        200,  70, 120,
        200,  70, 120,
        200,  70, 120,
        200,  70, 120,
        200,  70, 120,

          // left column back
        80, 70, 200,
        80, 70, 200,
        80, 70, 200,
        80, 70, 200,
        80, 70, 200,
        80, 70, 200,

          // top rung back
        80, 70, 200,
        80, 70, 200,
        80, 70, 200,
        80, 70, 200,
        80, 70, 200,
        80, 70, 200,

          // middle rung back
        80, 70, 200,
        80, 70, 200,
        80, 70, 200,
        80, 70, 200,
        80, 70, 200,
        80, 70, 200,

          // top
        70, 200, 210,
        70, 200, 210,
        70, 200, 210,
        70, 200, 210,
        70, 200, 210,
        70, 200, 210,

          // top rung right
        200, 200, 70,
        200, 200, 70,
        200, 200, 70,
        200, 200, 70,
        200, 200, 70,
        200, 200, 70,

          // under top rung
        210, 100, 70,
        210, 100, 70,
        210, 100, 70,
        210, 100, 70,
        210, 100, 70,
        210, 100, 70,

          // between top rung and middle
        210, 160, 70,
        210, 160, 70,
        210, 160, 70,
        210, 160, 70,
        210, 160, 70,
        210, 160, 70,

          // top of middle rung
        70, 180, 210,
        70, 180, 210,
        70, 180, 210,
        70, 180, 210,
        70, 180, 210,
        70, 180, 210,

          // right of middle rung
        100, 70, 210,
        100, 70, 210,
        100, 70, 210,
        100, 70, 210,
        100, 70, 210,
        100, 70, 210,

          // bottom of middle rung.
        76, 210, 100,
        76, 210, 100,
        76, 210, 100,
        76, 210, 100,
        76, 210, 100,
        76, 210, 100,

          // right of bottom
        140, 210, 80,
        140, 210, 80,
        140, 210, 80,
        140, 210, 80,
        140, 210, 80,
        140, 210, 80,

          // bottom
        90, 130, 110,
        90, 130, 110,
        90, 130, 110,
        90, 130, 110,
        90, 130, 110,
        90, 130, 110,

          // left side
        160, 160, 220,
        160, 160, 220,
        160, 160, 220,
        160, 160, 220,
        160, 160, 220,
        160, 160, 220,
      ]),
      gl.STATIC_DRAW);
}

main();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Traingle Webgl 2</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    @import url("https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-tutorials.css");

    body {
        margin: 0;
    }

    button {
        position: absolute;
    }

    canvas {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        display: block;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <script src="https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-utils.js"></script>
    <script src="https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/m4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-lessons-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="https://greggman.github.io/webgl-helpers/webgl-gl-error-check.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lookat.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What's the red at the bottom of the screenshot?

Comment: That was from chrome extension,  disappeared after I disabled it.

Comment: I'm just trying to track down why you didn't get an error and I did. I'm in Chrome as well. If you run your snippet above in stack overflow do you get an error?

Comment: No. I just get error for including lookat.js script link in html as 404 error. There is no error on webgl.

Comment: No error or warning !!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. With [the JavaScript console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/javascript) open in the browser, if I run your snippet I get this warning

   [image]

   That is a warning, not an error, that the code is trying to draw zero vertices. Checking the call to `gl.drawArrays` I found that `offset` and `count` were backward

   it was

   ```
   gl.drawArrays(primitives, count, offset);
   ```

   but in needs to be

   ```
   gl.drawArrays(primitives, offset, count);
   ```
2. Fixing that I got a new error

   > GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawArrays: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 0

   Looking through the code I saw you were drawing 16 * 6 vertices. I counted
   the data in both positions and colors and they were 16 * 6 so I went and
   looked at the code setting up the attributes. The code was using `gl.FLOAT` for the color attribute but it is using unsigned bytes for the color data.

   The code was

   ```
    type = gl.FLOAT;
    ...
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(acolorLoc, size, type, normalize, stride, offset);
   ```

   But needed to be

   ```
    type = gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE;
    ...
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(acolorLoc, size, type, normalize, stride, offset);
   ```
3. With that there are no more errors but nothing appeared on the screen.

   Looking at the camera code it was set to Z = -300 with the rotation set to 0. Camera looks down -Z by default so a camera at -300 is looking toward -Infinity in Z but the F is near the origin. Switching the camera to positive 300 so that it's looking back at the origin the F appears.

```js
"use strict";

const vertexShader = `#version 300 es

    in vec4 a_position;
    in vec4 a_color;

    out vec4 v_color;

    uniform mat4 u_matrix;

    void main(){
        gl_Position = u_matrix*a_position;
        v_color = a_color;
    }
`;


const fragShader = `#version 300 es

    precision highp float;

        in vec4 v_color;
        out vec4 frag_color;

        void main(){
            frag_color = v_color;
        }
`;


function main() {

    var canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
    var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl2");
    if (!gl) {
        return;
    }
    const program = webglUtils.createProgramFromSources(gl, [vertexShader, fragShader]);

    const apositionLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'a_position');
    const acolorLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'a_color');
    const umatrixLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'u_matrix');

    let vao = gl.createVertexArray();
    gl.bindVertexArray(vao);

    let positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
    setGeometry(gl);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(apositionLoc);

    let size = 3;
    let type = gl.FLOAT;
    let normalize = false;
    let stride = 0;
    let offset = 0;
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(apositionLoc, size, type, normalize, stride, offset);

    let colorBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);
    setColor(gl);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(acolorLoc);

    size = 3;
    type = gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE;
    normalize = true;
    stride = 0;
    offset = 0;
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(acolorLoc, size, type, normalize, stride, offset);

    let fov = degreeToRadian(60);
    let cameraAngle = degreeToRadian(0);

    function degreeToRadian(deg) {
        return deg * Math.PI / 180;
    }

    drawScene();


    function drawScene() {

        webglUtils.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);

        gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

        gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);

        gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
        
        gl.useProgram(program);

        let aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
        
        let projection = m4.perspective(fov, aspect, 1, 1000);

        let camera = m4.yRotation(cameraAngle);
        camera = m4.translate(camera, 0, 0, 300);
        let viewMatrix = m4.inverse(camera);

        let viewProjection = m4.multiply(projection, viewMatrix);

        gl.uniformMatrix4fv(umatrixLoc, false, viewProjection);
        
        var primitives = gl.TRIANGLES;
        var count = 16*6;
        var offset = 0;
        gl.drawArrays(primitives, offset, count);

    }

}

function setGeometry(gl){

    let positions = new Float32Array([

          0,   0,  0,
          0, 150,  0,
          30,   0,  0,
          0, 150,  0,
          30, 150,  0,
          30,   0,  0,

          // top rung front
          30,   0,  0,
          30,  30,  0,
          100,   0,  0,
          30,  30,  0,
          100,  30,  0,
          100,   0,  0,

          // middle rung front
          30,  60,  0,
          30,  90,  0,
          67,  60,  0,
          30,  90,  0,
          67,  90,  0,
          67,  60,  0,

          // left column back
            0,   0,  30,
           30,   0,  30,
            0, 150,  30,
            0, 150,  30,
           30,   0,  30,
           30, 150,  30,

          // top rung back
           30,   0,  30,
          100,   0,  30,
           30,  30,  30,
           30,  30,  30,
          100,   0,  30,
          100,  30,  30,

          // middle rung back
           30,  60,  30,
           67,  60,  30,
           30,  90,  30,
           30,  90,  30,
           67,  60,  30,
           67,  90,  30,

          // top
            0,   0,   0,
          100,   0,   0,
          100,   0,  30,
            0,   0,   0,
          100,   0,  30,
            0,   0,  30,

          // top rung right
          100,   0,   0,
          100,  30,   0,
          100,  30,  30,
          100,   0,   0,
          100,  30,  30,
          100,   0,  30,

          // under top rung
          30,   30,   0,
          30,   30,  30,
          100,  30,  30,
          30,   30,   0,
          100,  30,  30,
          100,  30,   0,

          // between top rung and middle
          30,   30,   0,
          30,   60,  30,
          30,   30,  30,
          30,   30,   0,
          30,   60,   0,
          30,   60,  30,

          // top of middle rung
          30,   60,   0,
          67,   60,  30,
          30,   60,  30,
          30,   60,   0,
          67,   60,   0,
          67,   60,  30,

          // right of middle rung
          67,   60,   0,
          67,   90,  30,
          67,   60,  30,
          67,   60,   0,
          67,   90,   0,
          67,   90,  30,

          // bottom of middle rung.
          30,   90,   0,
          30,   90,  30,
          67,   90,  30,
          30,   90,   0,
          67,   90,  30,
          67,   90,   0,

          // right of bottom
          30,   90,   0,
          30,  150,  30,
          30,   90,  30,
          30,   90,   0,
          30,  150,   0,
          30,  150,  30,

          // bottom
          0,   150,   0,
          0,   150,  30,
          30,  150,  30,
          0,   150,   0,
          30,  150,  30,
          30,  150,   0,

          // left side
          0,   0,   0,
          0,   0,  30,
          0, 150,  30,
          0,   0,   0,
          0, 150,  30,
          0, 150,   0,

    ]);

    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positions, gl.STATIC_DRAW)
}

function setColor(gl){
gl.bufferData(
      gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
      new Uint8Array([
          // left column front
        200,  70, 120,
        200,  70, 120,
        200,  70, 120,
        200,  70, 120,
        200,  70, 120,
        200,  70, 120,

          // top rung front
        200,  70, 120,
        200,  70, 120,
        200,  70, 120,
        200,  70, 120,
        200,  70, 120,
        200,  70, 120,

          // middle rung front
        200,  70, 120,
        200,  70, 120,
        200,  70, 120,
        200,  70, 120,
        200,  70, 120,
        200,  70, 120,

          // left column back
        80, 70, 200,
        80, 70, 200,
        80, 70, 200,
        80, 70, 200,
        80, 70, 200,
        80, 70, 200,

          // top rung back
        80, 70, 200,
        80, 70, 200,
        80, 70, 200,
        80, 70, 200,
        80, 70, 200,
        80, 70, 200,

          // middle rung back
        80, 70, 200,
        80, 70, 200,
        80, 70, 200,
        80, 70, 200,
        80, 70, 200,
        80, 70, 200,

          // top
        70, 200, 210,
        70, 200, 210,
        70, 200, 210,
        70, 200, 210,
        70, 200, 210,
        70, 200, 210,

          // top rung right
        200, 200, 70,
        200, 200, 70,
        200, 200, 70,
        200, 200, 70,
        200, 200, 70,
        200, 200, 70,

          // under top rung
        210, 100, 70,
        210, 100, 70,
        210, 100, 70,
        210, 100, 70,
        210, 100, 70,
        210, 100, 70,

          // between top rung and middle
        210, 160, 70,
        210, 160, 70,
        210, 160, 70,
        210, 160, 70,
        210, 160, 70,
        210, 160, 70,

          // top of middle rung
        70, 180, 210,
        70, 180, 210,
        70, 180, 210,
        70, 180, 210,
        70, 180, 210,
        70, 180, 210,

          // right of middle rung
        100, 70, 210,
        100, 70, 210,
        100, 70, 210,
        100, 70, 210,
        100, 70, 210,
        100, 70, 210,

          // bottom of middle rung.
        76, 210, 100,
        76, 210, 100,
        76, 210, 100,
        76, 210, 100,
        76, 210, 100,
        76, 210, 100,

          // right of bottom
        140, 210, 80,
        140, 210, 80,
        140, 210, 80,
        140, 210, 80,
        140, 210, 80,
        140, 210, 80,

          // bottom
        90, 130, 110,
        90, 130, 110,
        90, 130, 110,
        90, 130, 110,
        90, 130, 110,
        90, 130, 110,

          // left side
        160, 160, 220,
        160, 160, 220,
        160, 160, 220,
        160, 160, 220,
        160, 160, 220,
        160, 160, 220,
      ]),
      gl.STATIC_DRAW);
}

main();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Traingle Webgl 2</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    @import url("https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-tutorials.css");

    body {
        margin: 0;
    }

    button {
        position: absolute;
    }

    canvas {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        display: block;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <script src="https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-utils.js"></script>
    <script src="https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/m4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-lessons-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="https://greggman.github.io/webgl-helpers/webgl-gl-error-check.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lookat.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

You should try to learn to use the [browser's developer tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools). They might not have found every bug but they would at least have given you error messages for the first 2.

Comment: i have updated the question, there was no console error. Thanks for your answer and website that is great source of learning.

Comment: I have updated the code. Could you please tell me why the F are not rotating in a circle ?    I want to understand why this is happening so that i can understand the working better.

Comment: Please ask a new question. Editing your question makes the answer irrelevant. S.O. is not a forum. It's a question and answer site.